# Exiting PCL viewer: wasStopped() not changing value even though window was closed

Tags: c++, visualization, point-cloud-library

I've been trying to use the PCL Visualizer according to [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) on the PCL website and am using the following methods to visualize a point cloud:

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> createViewer (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud, std::string& viewerName) 
{ 
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer (viewerName)); 

    viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0); 
    viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud, viewerName); 
    viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, viewerName); 
    viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0); 
    viewer->initCameraParameters (); 

    return viewer; 
} 

void visualizePointCloud (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud) 
{ 
    std::string viewerName = "3D Viewer: Cloud"; 

    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer; 
    viewer = createViewer(cloud, viewerName); 

    while (!viewer->wasStopped()) 
    { 
        viewer->spinOnce(100); 
        boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000)); 
    } 
}
```

Everything visualizes fine, but I can't seem to get out of the loop! 
If you close the viewer window by clicking the "x", nothing happens, `wasStopped()` still returns `false`, and the program is stuck.

Anybody know how to terminate the viewer properly so the program can go on with the rest of the code? Am I just being stupid? 
Many thanks in advance!

P.S.: I´m on Mac OS 10.13.6 with PCL 1.8.1 (installed via Homebrew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit embarrased, but the answer is really simple... accicentally stumbled onto it after trying Flumenque's solution... As it turns out everything was working like it should, I was just too simple to realize it:

The viewer can be terminated with a press of "q" on the keyboard. However, you have to click inside the visualization area first, even if the window already has the focus!

Thought I'd write it up just in case somebody else matches my stupidity... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can close an open viewer at any time with the method

```
viewer->close();
```

I guess it was added in PCL 1.6: http://www.pcl-users.org/How-to-close-the-window-of-a-PCLViewer-and-how-to-make-it-stop-by-code-td3824712.html

Comment: Thanks for your hint @Flumenque. It is working to close the viewer. However it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to check if the user has closed the viewer window. Any hint on how I can check if the window has been closed in order to then use your proposed method?